JavaFX trigger ChoiceBox converter (and sort by the String value)
I have a ChoiceBox<Locale> and a ChoiceBox<SavingOrder> (an enum created by me, which has only a geti18nKey() method) and I need to update the SavingOrder translation when the Locale changes.
Is there any way to trigger its converter? Also, can I sort the shown Strings?
setChoiceBoxItems(settingsLangCB, supportedLocales);
settingsLangCB.setConverter(new StringConverter<Locale>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Locale locale) {
        String str = locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale);
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    }

    @Override
    public Locale fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
});
settingsLangCB.getSelectionModel().select(ioManager.getLoginAccount().getLocale());
settingsLangCB.setOnAction(event -> {
    Locale locale = settingsLangCB.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    langResources.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/bundles/Lang", locale));
    ioManager.getLoginAccount().setLocale(locale);
    // TODO on lang change call settingsOrderCB's converter so that is displayed in the right lang
    // and sort it by the associated String value
    setMainTitle(langResources.getValue("settings"));
});

setChoiceBoxItems(settingsOrderCB, SavingOrder.class.getEnumConstants());
settingsOrderCB.setConverter(new StringConverter<SavingOrder>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(SavingOrder savingOrder) {
        return langResources.getValue(savingOrder.i18nKey());
    }

    @Override
    public SavingOrder fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
});
settingsOrderCB.getSelectionModel().select(ioManager.getLoginAccount().getSavingOrder());
settingsOrderCB.setOnAction(event -> {
    SavingOrder savingOrder = settingsOrderCB.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    ioManager.getLoginAccount().setSavingOrder(savingOrder);
    ioManager.sortAccountList();
});


There is no mechanism to trigger an update when the internal state of a StringConverter changes. What you can do, however, is replace the current converter with a new one. The best way to do this is to bind the converter property of the ChoiceBox.
You can use a SortedList to sort the items of the ChoiceBox. A custom Comparator can be used to sort the items based on their string representations, using the existing converter for consistency. Though much like before, there is no mechanism for triggering an update if the internal state of the Comparator changes. You will need to replace the comparator as needed, which again is best done via binding.

Proof of Concept
Here is a proof-of-concept demonstrating the above.
SavingOrder.java
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

// No idea what your real SavingOrder enum looks like, so
// this is just a dummy.
public enum SavingOrder {
  ASC("order.asc"),
  DESC("order.desc");

  private final String i18nKey;

  SavingOrder(String i18nKey) {
    this.i18nKey = i18nKey;
  }

  public String getDisplayName(Locale locale) {
    if (locale == null) {
      locale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY);
    }
    var bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles/SavingOrder", locale);
    return bundle.getString(i18nKey);
  }
}

Main.java
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Main extends Application {

  private static List<Locale> getSupportedLanguages() {
    // TODO: Modify list to include only languages you want to support.
    return List.of(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.FRENCH, Locale.GERMAN, Locale.ITALIAN);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var langBox = createLanguageBox();
    var orderBox = createSavingOrderBox(langBox.valueProperty());

    var root = new GridPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    root.setHgap(10);
    root.setVgap(10);
    root.addRow(0, langBox, orderBox);

    var rowCon = new RowConstraints();
    rowCon.setPercentHeight(100);
    rowCon.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
    root.getRowConstraints().add(rowCon);

    var colCon = new ColumnConstraints();
    colCon.setPercentWidth(50);
    colCon.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
    root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colCon, colCon);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 150));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private ChoiceBox<Locale> createLanguageBox() {
    var langs = FXCollections.observableList(getSupportedLanguages());
    var sortedLangs = langs.sorted(null);

    var langBox = new ChoiceBox<>(sortedLangs);
    langBox.setValue(langs.getFirst());
    langBox
        .converterProperty()
        .bind(langBox.valueProperty().map(this::displayLanguageStringConverter));
    sortedLangs
        .comparatorProperty()
        .bind(comparator(langBox.valueProperty(), langBox.converterProperty()));

    return langBox;
  }

  private ChoiceBox<SavingOrder> createSavingOrderBox(ObservableValue<Locale> locale) {
    var orders = FXCollections.observableArrayList(SavingOrder.values());
    var sortedOrders = orders.sorted(null);

    var orderBox = new ChoiceBox<>(sortedOrders);
    orderBox.setValue(orders.getFirst());
    orderBox.converterProperty().bind(locale.map(this::savingOrderStringConverter));
    sortedOrders.comparatorProperty().bind(comparator(locale, orderBox.converterProperty()));

    return orderBox;
  }

  private StringConverter<Locale> displayLanguageStringConverter(Locale locale) {
    return toStringConverter(item -> item.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
  }

  private StringConverter<SavingOrder> savingOrderStringConverter(Locale locale) {
    return toStringConverter(item -> item.getDisplayName(locale));
  }

  private <T> StringConverter<T> toStringConverter(Callback<? super T, String> converter) {
    return new StringConverter<>() {

      @Override
      public T fromString(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }

      @Override
      public String toString(T object) {
        return converter.call(object);
      }
    };
  }

  private <T> ObservableValue<Comparator<T>> comparator(
      ObservableValue<Locale> locale, ObservableValue<? extends StringConverter<T>> converter) {
    return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
        () -> {
          var collator = Collator.getInstance(locale.getValue());
          /*
           * This comparator converts the items to a string using the same converter
           * as used to display the items. It then uses the given Collator to compare
           * the strings. You don't have to use a Collator if you don't want to. If you
           * don't, then you can simply remove the second argument since String
           * implements Comparable.
           */
          return Comparator.comparing(converter.getValue()::toString, collator);
        },
        locale,
        converter);
  }
}

bundles/SavingOrder.properties
order.asc  = Ascending
order.desc = Descending

This is the fallback bundle. Add bundles to support more languages.
 

I found a "lazy" solution as mentioned in my answer. But yes I think binding is far better, so I'll try to implement it. thanks

Your "lazy" solution is likely easier to implement short term. Though note that the built-in binding implementations try to be as lazy as possible (they only compute the value if the binding is currently invalid and only upon request). I've edited my answer to provide a proof-of-concept.

I adapted it to my actual code and works perfeclty. It's also much more readable than my solution... ty!

I found a solution:
Apparently I just had to call the sort() method using a custom comparator, which comparates the string values (by calling the toString() method on the order converter, which is now stored as a constant) and give it a string comparator (like a Collator instance, which is optional since String already implements Comparable).
This sorts the list, but also updates the shown text, since langResources has already been updated with the new Locale.
settingsOrderCB.getItems().sort(Comparator.comparing(
    ORDER_CONVERTER::toString,
    Collator.getInstance(ioManager.getLoginAccount().getLocale())
));

Note: This is a pretty lazy workaround to Slaw's answer, but using object binding might result in cleaner code and could save a lot of headaches later.
